# Gantt Chart with sum on Jquery - Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, charts

I'm trying to make a Gantt Chart on Laravel with a total sum of hours, but I'm not able to find a library to make it and I don't know how could I make it.

I leave you a picture in Excel:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, tutorials or other off-site resources are are considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow, as the recommendations are subject to personal opinion. Please refer to the StackOverflow help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the documentation for topics that are considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)'. Please attempt something, then come back with a **specific** code problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do exactly what you want:

https://github.com/swatkins/laravel-gantt

But you do need a fairly good understanding of Laravel (maybe even basics) to get this implemented.

Comment: I found it time ago, I need put a value for each day... to make a sum... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use Google chars: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart